# How to choose a json structure for data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In this case the first variable is always the ID, the second variable is always the OCR number and the third number is always the amount. Then would it make any difference to do either in this way:

```
{
    "Transactions": [
        "23/2/2014 @ 16:48:8",
        [
            [
                "ID",
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "OCR",
                "123456789"
            ],
            [
                "Amount",
                "100"
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                "ID",
                "2"
            ],
            [
                "OCR",
                "987654321"
            ],
            [
                "Amount",
                "20"
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Or the equivalent input with just the input data since we know that the index will be the same for the different values:

```
{
    "Transactions": [
        "23/2/2014 @ 16:48:8",
        [
            [
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "123456789"
            ],
            [
                "100"
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                "2"
            ],
            [
                "987654321"
            ],
            [
                "20"
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
{
    "Transactions": [
        "23/2/2014 @ 16:48:8",
        [
            "1",
            "123456789",
            "100"
        ],
        [
            "2",
            "987654321",
            "20"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Or minimally:

```
{
    "23/2/2014 @ 16:48:8": [
        [
            "1",
            "123456789",
            "100"
        ],
        [
            "2",
            "987654321",
            "20"
        ]
    ]
}
```

But I don't thnk that the following is good style even though it would work if you know which element is which and just post an array:

```
{
    "23/2/2014 @ 16:48:8": [
        123456789,
        100,
        987654321,
        20
    ]
}
```

Or just an array (that is also valid json and contains all we need to know):

```
[
    123456789,
    100,
    987654321,
    20
]
```

Even though all the exampled appear to be valid json, it might be preferred to go in either direction, either a structure which is less readable and monimally just an array, or a structure that is named and more complex but also more readable even though a number can represent what time it is, it might be preferable to store it as a string and similar to have a label what some data is.

In my last example you must know that every second element is an amount and every other element is an OCR reference.

There is also an alternative that is valid json like this:

```
{
    "23/2/2014 @ 16:48:8": [
        [
            {
                "OCR": 123456789
            },
            {
                "Amount": 100
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "OCR": 987654321
            },
            {
                "Amount": 200
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

So I'm not sure how to represent the elements and lists.

Comment: So, do you want us to choose the look of your data for you?

Comment: what kind of operation will you do with json? sorting? selection? etc? It's core question for your data

Comment: Just use the format you find most useful when working with it.

Comment: According to me this question would be properly suited at programmers.stackexchange.com as it demands for a discussion. And stackoverflow is for solving a problems in code. This is my point of view. :)

Comment: @Bhavik: [programmers.se] is not for discussions, it's meant for questions that are more conceptual than what's accepted at Stack Overflow. That doesn't meant that all discussions and off-topic questions are suitable here. See [this Meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in/129632#129632) for more information about which site's suitable for what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only you can decide what it should look like in the end, but here are a couple of suggestions...

Stay away from using data as keys...

```
{
    "23/2/2014 @ 16:48:8": []
}
```

Instead do something like this...

```
{
    "timestamp": "23/2/2014 @ 16:48:8",
    "data": []
}
```

And your use of arrays seem better suited as objects. Here's an example of what I think is an acceptable representation...

```
{
    "transactions": [
        { "id": 1, "timestamp": "23/2/2014 @ 16:48:8", "ocr": 12345678, "amount": 500 },
        { "id": 2, "timestamp": "23/2/2014 @ 16:48:9", "ocr": 345435, "amount": 200}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best format really depends upon how you want to consume the data.  But, generally I think of data like this as a collection of objects where each transaction is an object that has properties.  In that vein, something like an array of transactions would make sense:

```
{
    "Transactions": [
        {
            "time": "23/2/2014 @ 16:48:8",
            "id": "1",
            "ocr": "123456789",
            "amount": "100"
        },
        {
            "time": "23/2/2014 @ 16:48:8",
            "id": "2",
            "ocr": "987654321",
            "amount": "200"
        }
    ]
}
```

This lets you loop through the transactions and then access each of the properties of each transaction.